# Get all available filters in queryset

Tags: python, django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am building a search page using elastic search and Django Haystack. What I am looking to achieve is to show filters form on the results page, but I am trying to make this more dynamic so am wondering if there is a way to get all possible filters on queryset regardless of which module the result belongs to. ([Example for what I am trying to acheive](http://postimg.org/image/w2vn2h54f/))

Reason I am trying to do this because not all my models have the same fields.

If this is isn't the right way to do it, then how would I build this using good practices.
 OR
Should I just build this the manual way with if conditions and some ugly logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into faceting?

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html

It gives you feedback on documents that are matched by the users query and you can build filters from that.

Comment: Faceting is for count right. How can I use that to give me such info ?

Comment: True, faceting gives you the counts but you can use the faceting result to get a list of all the filters you can facet on and use that for building your filter page.